# Discover the current user's screensaver timeout either programmatically or via commandline on a mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, command-line, screensaver

Does anyone know how to discover what the timeout is for the screensaver of the current user on a mac. I would prefer a programmatic method if possible but am also happy to parse the output of a command line utility. I am already doing this with pmset to get the sleep times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value for screensaver settings for current user in (at least from 10.6.x upwards) stored in a [property list file](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist`. It is possible that there is no value, in case the user has decided to disable automatic screen blanking/saving.

You can read the value with a command line utility called [defaults(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html):

```
defaults read com.apple.screensaver idleTime
defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver idleTime
```

The former provides access to settings of current user, the latter to system defaults, should one exist.

Reading values with defaults(1) is somewhat complicated as the value may or may not be present. It'd be sane to assume that `defaults read com.apple.screensaver idleTime` would return zero in case the current user has disabled the screensaver, but that's not the case. Instead defaults(1) will toss an error message on the terminal and return non-zero exit code. Instead of just parsing the output of defaults(1), you'd have to first check the exit code and do parsing only in case it's zero. On the other hand, that might be a sane policy to follow anyway when parsing output of external commands.

Apple provides [programming interfaces with their Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPropertyLists/CFPropertyLists.html) for reading/writing [property lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html) as well.

Comment: Although this appears to work nicely from Terminal, sadly it does not work when I call it from my sandboxed application. Both versions give me an error from 'defaults' as follows: `The domain/default pair of (com.apple.screensaver, idleTime) does not exist`. I will look into opening the plist as you suggest.

Comment: Does your sandboxed application have access to files in users home directory? In case it doesn't, even plist-api doesn't provide you with an access to values stored in `~/Library/Preferenc ...`.

Comment: I suspect that by default it wont since it is not part of my app's sandbox. This might mean that I may have to ask the user for permission to access that file or at least the preferences folder, and then store a scoped bookmark to it so I don't pester the user.

Comment: Although this is not a complete answer due to the fact that by itself it does not work for sandboxed apps, it is still mostly correct. To make it work for sandboxed apps you need to add a temporary exception for shared preferences on com.apple.screensaver to your app's entitlements. I am not sure how well this will go over yet with apple. I guess I will find out after the next submission of my app. :)

Comment: This property does not exist in 10.11. Not sure about where is it being moved.

Comment: Yes this plist doesnot exist in 10.11. Can any one help me what is the replacement for it

Answer (score 5):

As a follow-up to the correct original answer (in a response to the comments on that answer about El Capitan), it seems that the above property does not exist in 10.11 for the set of default values, but it *does* exist for `currentHost`:

```
$ defaults read com.apple.screensaver
{
    askForPassword = 1;
    askForPasswordDelay = 5;
    tokenRemovalAction = 0;
}
```

and then for `currentHost`:

```
$ defaults -currentHost write com.apple.screensaver idleTime 60
$ defaults -currentHost read com.apple.screensaver
{
    PrefsVersion = 100;
    idleTime = 60;
    moduleDict =     {
        moduleName = iLifeSlideshows;
        path = "/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/iLifeSlideshows.saver";
        type = 0;
    };
    showClock = 0;
    tokenRemovalAction = 0;
}
```

The above `write` command sets the idle time for my user, which is what I was looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: What units are these? `idleTime` appears to be in seconds, but what unit is used for `askForPasswordDelay`?